# How to disable Cortana's commute alerts?

Tags: 8.1, cortana

Recently Cortana has become concerned with whether or not I get to work on time every morning:

[image]

This pops up as an alert on my phone, and is kind of annoying, especially since the directions she shows aren't actually useful to me (they're for driving, but I take the bus). Is there any way to turn them off?

I can see in the "interests" section of Cortana's notebook that this seems to be part of the Daily Glance item, but I don't want to turn that off entirely as I do like seeing the weather forecast and upcoming appointments. Is there a way to disable *only* commute alerts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "time to go to work or head home" option is in: **Cortana** > **Cortana's Notebook** (The settings) > **interests** > **getting around**

At the bottom there is an option to "Notify me when it's time to go to work or head home" - just uncheck that and press the save button.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks! I didn't even notice that section.